# zend mod rewrite OR routing

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, mod-rewrite, zend-route

I use Zend Framework in my web application. I have the next URL: `domain/user/user/username`. Where first `user` is a controller in the `default` module. Second `user` is a `GET` variable. `username` is a value of this variable. All good. But for the good usability I want to have the next URL: `domain/user/username`. I know that by Zend GET rules it should be as my first variant. But maybe I can do this with mod rewriting or Zend_Route? Help me, please.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Dunno if your framework would allow it, but why not to have username as a GET variable?

Comment: Thanks. If I don't find another solution I do like you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `/application/configs/routes.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<routes>
    <user>
      <route>user/:username/*</route>
      <defaults>
          <module>default</module>
          <controller>user</controller>
          <action>view</action>
          <username>0</username>
      </defaults>
    </user>
</routes>
```

Then in `Bootstrap.php`:

```
public function _initRouter()
{
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $router = $front->getRouter();
    $config = new Zend_Config_Xml(dirname(__FILE__) . '/configs/routes.xml');
    $router->addConfig($config);

    return $router;
}
```

You may also do the same in a lot of other ways, e.g. in `application.ini`.

Comment: Thank you. It is very good answer. But my application based on `.ini` configuration files. Can you give me example with ini config?

Comment: @Alexander Yes, I could, but you are being to lazy to read the manual of [Zend_Application_Resource_Router](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html) ;)

Answer (score 1):

In your application.ini, add:

```
resources.router.routes.article.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
resources.router.routes.article.route = "user/:username/*"
resources.router.routes.article.defaults.module = "default"
resources.router.routes.article.defaults.controller = "user"
resources.router.routes.article.defaults.action = "view"
resources.router.routes.article.reqs.username = "guest"
```

and I suggest you to have a look at:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html